# getting error while unzipping

Tags: java, android-studio, zip, inputstream, unzip

My UnZip class does not unzip whole the file. This class is called from another activity. My zip file is saved in the main directory of the phone's internal storage. The zip file has folders and some video.
What's wrong with this unzip?
What and how should I read file from zip' decompress and unzip is the same meaning?

Thanks for your help!

```
public class Unzip {
  private static final String INPUT_ZIP_FILE = "sdcard/downloaded_issue.zip";
  private static final String OUTPUT_FOLDER = "sdcard/Atlantis/";

  public static void main()
  {
    Unzip unZip = new Unzip();
    unZip.unZipIt(INPUT_ZIP_FILE, OUTPUT_FOLDER);
  }

/**
 * Unzip it
 * @param zipFile input zip file
 * @param outputFolder zip file output folder
 */
public void unZipIt(String zipFile, String outputFolder){
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    try{

        //create output directory is not exists
        File folder = new File(OUTPUT_FOLDER);
        if(!folder.exists()){
            folder.mkdir();
        }

        //get the zip file content
        ZipInputStream zis =
                new ZipInputStream(new FileInputStream(zipFile));
        //get the zipped file list entry
        ZipEntry ze = zis.getNextEntry();

        while(ze!=null){

            String fileName = ze.getName();
            File newFile = new File(outputFolder + File.separator + fileName);

            System.out.println("file unzip : "+ newFile.getAbsoluteFile());

            //create all non exists folders
            //else you will hit FileNotFoundException for compressed folder
            new File(newFile.getParent()).mkdirs();

            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(newFile);

            int len;
            while ((len = zis.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                fos.write(buffer, 0, len);
            }

            fos.close();
            if (ze.isDirectory()) {
            ze = zis.getNextEntry();
            }
        }

        zis.closeEntry();
        zis.close();

        System.out.println("Done");

    }catch(IOException ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Which programming language is this? Looks like either Java or C# at first glance.

Comment: It is Java. and I'm programming with Android Studio

Comment: Tag it as such, then. You'll get much faster response if the programming language is included; people tend to filter on that.

Comment: Which tag do you suggest?

Comment: Looks like you did it right. Not much more I can do; I'm not too familiar with java's zip systems myself, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I think your 'while' loop is broken; you're only fetching the next entry if that next entry is a directory, while I assume you're probably trying to *skip* the directories.

Anyway, since you create the folders for all files you encounter, you can just skip the folder entries and write the file entries. The only exception would be the creation of empty folders.

Replacing the while-loop by this code should work:

```
    while(ze!=null){
        String fileName = ze.getName();
        File newFile = new File(outputFolder + File.separator + fileName);
        System.out.println("file unzip : "+ newFile.getAbsoluteFile());
        //create all non exists folders
        //else you will hit FileNotFoundException for compressed folder
        if (ze.isDirectory()) {
            // create the folder
            newFile.mkdirs();
        }
        else {
            // create the parent folder and write to disk
            new File(newFile.getParent()).mkdirs();
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(newFile);
            int len;
            while ((len = zis.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                fos.write(buffer, 0, len);
            }
            fos.close();
        }
        // get the next item
        ze = zis.getNextEntry();
    }
```

Comment: I need to extract all folders. Not skip them.

Comment: No, wait. This isn't recursive, and folder entries themselves, unless the folder is empty, don't have any value since you auto-create the folders for files anyway. the best you can do is create them and then skip them, yes.

Comment: @Weblu Edited the answer. Though in reality the only thing this changes is that empty folders get created.